# Correct Way To Remove Class On Second Click

Tags: jquery, click, addclass, removeclass

I have multiple divs that on mouse click get a class added.

What is the appropriate way to remove the added class on that particular div on *a second click of that item*. I have not been able to remove the class.

```
jQuery('.icon-box').on('click', function() {

  var isActive = false;
  jQuery(this).addClass('clicked');

  if (jQuery(this).hasClass('clicked')) {
    var isActive = true;
  }
  if ( isActive ) {
    jQuery(this).removeClass('clicked');
  }

});
```

[JSFiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/s0tf2oo4/).

Thank you for the feedback.

Comment: You are adding class clicked before checking if element has this class...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
jQuery('.icon-box').on('click', function() {
 if (jQuery(this).hasClass('clicked')) {
   $(this).removeClass('clicked');
  }
  else
  {
   $(this).addClass('clicked');
  }

});
```

Comment: Thanks, for my particular instance, it was correct.

Answer (score 4):

Do you mean something like this:

```
jQuery('.icon-box').on('click', function() {
   jQuery(this).toggleClass('clicked');
});
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/csak9k4q/1/

You can find more information about this in the jQuery docs:
http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/

Comment: Thanks, I was not aware of that. I'll read up more on using that. For my particular instance, it was not correct.